# Confusing Results from diff

Tags: diff

I got the following results from diff:

```
@@ -4479,7 +4479,7 @@
         || AddPrintCheckParameters(TRUE)
         || AddRecipeDefaults(TRUE)
         || AddRepeatScanPass(TRUE)
-        || AddVirgoFlag(TRUE)        
+        || AddVirgoFlag(TRUE)
         || AddAttrPatchSize(TRUE)
         || AddDualSensParameters(TRUE)
         || AddMDATDensitySP(TRUE)
```

Seems that it suggesting me to delete and add the same line. Why?

Comment: Blank characters maybe?  Try with `-E -Z -b -w`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By selecting both lines with the mouse to they are highlighted, I can clearly see that the first (deleted) line has trailing spaces that the second does not.

If you use `diff -w` this difference would be ignored by diff.

Comment: Exactly. Thanks!